# ListView fade out in animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have some problem with ListView animation: How can I realize "fade out" animation of elements in ListView? I need to have only six elements on the screen and such animation, like on the picture.

[image: Example of animation]

I only managed to make a "fade in" animation, and it's not exactly, what I need.

```
package com.example.testmalyutinoleksandr;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private ListView listview;
  private TextView textView;

  private Context con;

  private static final String LABELSKEY = "myListLabels";
  private static final String COUNTERSKEY = "myListCounters";
  private String values [];
  private int counters [];

  private static Calendar currentDate;
  private Timer timer;

  static {

        currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    con = this;

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(LABELSKEY))
    {
        values = savedInstanceState.getStringArray(LABELSKEY);
        counters = savedInstanceState.getIntArray(COUNTERSKEY);
    }
    else
    {
        values = DataLoader.getTitles(getApplication());
        counters = new int [] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    }

    SimpleListAdapter adapter = new SimpleListAdapter(this, values, counters);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                    public void run() {
                          currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                          int hour = currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                          int minutes = currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                          int seconds = currentDate.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                          textView.setText( hour + ":" + (minutes<10?"0":"") + minutes  + ":" +  (seconds<10?"0":"") + seconds);
                      }
                  }
                );            
            }
        } , 1, 1*1000);


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TextView counterTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);
            int counter = Integer.valueOf(counterTextView.getText().toString());
            counter++;
            counterTextView.setText(counter + "");
            MainActivity.this.counters[position] = counter;

            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Нажата кнопка " + (position+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


      listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {


            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);

            alert.setTitle("Title");
            alert.setMessage("Message");
            final EditText input = new EditText(con);
            input.setText("");
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      // the adapter you set in the listView.setAdapter();

                    values[position] = input.getText().toString();
                    SimpleListAdapter adapter = new SimpleListAdapter(con, values, counters);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });


            alert.show();
        return true;
        }
      });     
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
  {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      outState.putStringArray(LABELSKEY, values);
      outState.putIntArray(COUNTERSKEY, counters);
  }

}
```

And here is the code of Adapter:

```
package com.example.testmalyutinoleksandr;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SimpleListAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
      private final Context context;
      private final String[] values;

      private final int[] counters;

      private ArrayList<Drawable> icons;
      private ArrayList<Drawable> bcgnd;




      public SimpleListAdapter(Context context, String[] values, int [] counters1) {
        super(context, R.layout.one_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.counters = counters1;
        this.icons = DataLoader.getIconsRandomly(context);
        this.bcgnd = DataLoader.getBackgrounds(context);            
      }



      static class ViewHolder {
            public ImageView iconImageView;
            public TextView titleTextView;
            public TextView counterTextView;
        }


      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          ViewHolder holder;
          View rowView = convertView;

          if(rowView == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.iconImageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
            holder.titleTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            holder.counterTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);


            rowView.setTag(holder);


          }else{
              holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
          }




          holder.iconImageView.setImageDrawable(icons.get(position));
          rowView.setBackgroundDrawable(bcgnd.get(position));
          holder.titleTextView.setText(values[position]);
          holder.counterTextView.setText(counters[position] + "");



          Animation animation = null;

          animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.test_set);
          animation.setDuration(500);
          rowView.startAnimation(animation);
          animation = null;

          return rowView;
      }
    }
```

So, can you tell me, what should I do?

**EDIT 1**

I managed to do this type of animation with code

```
package com.example.testmalyutinoleksandr;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private ListView listview;
  private TextView textView;

  private Context con;

  private static final String LABELSKEY = "myListLabels";
  private static final String COUNTERSKEY = "myListCounters";
  private String values [];
  private int counters [];

  private static Calendar currentDate;
  private Timer timer;

  SimpleListAdapter adapter;


  private static volatile float prevX= 1;
  //private static int prevY = 1;

  private static volatile int width;
  private static volatile int height;
  private static volatile boolean flag = true;



  AbsListView view;
  int visibleItemCount;


  static {

        currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    con = this;

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(LABELSKEY))
    {
        values = savedInstanceState.getStringArray(LABELSKEY);
        counters = savedInstanceState.getIntArray(COUNTERSKEY);
    }
    else
    {
        values = DataLoader.getTitles(getApplication());
        counters = new int [] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    }

    adapter = new SimpleListAdapter(this, values, counters);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    Log.d("myLogs", "onCreate run");



    timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                    public void run() {
                          currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                          int hour = currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                          int minutes = currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                          int seconds = currentDate.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                          textView.setText( hour + ":" + (minutes<10?"0":"") + minutes  + ":" +  (seconds<10?"0":"") + seconds);
                      }
                  }
                );            
            }
        } , 1, 1*1000);


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TextView counterTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);
            int counter = Integer.valueOf(counterTextView.getText().toString());
            counter++;
            counterTextView.setText(counter + "");
            MainActivity.this.counters[position] = counter;

            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Нажата кнопка " + (position+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


      listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {


            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);

            alert.setTitle("Title");
            alert.setMessage("Message");
            final EditText input = new EditText(con);
            input.setText("");
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      // the adapter you set in the listView.setAdapter();

                    values[position] = input.getText().toString();
                    SimpleListAdapter adapter = new SimpleListAdapter(con, values, counters);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });


            alert.show();
        return true;
        }
      });



      listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            int pos = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();




            ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(MainActivity.prevX, (float)(MainActivity.prevX+0.001), MainActivity.prevX, (float)(MainActivity.prevX+0.001), 300, 100);
            scaleAnimation.setDuration(1);



            Log.d("myLogs", "Params: " + MainActivity.prevX);


            View firstView = view.getChildAt(0);


            firstView.setAnimation(scaleAnimation);
            firstView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);


            firstView.invalidate();

            //}
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            MainActivity.this.view = view;
            MainActivity.this.visibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                    public void run() {

            int [] location = {-1,-1};
            MainActivity.this.view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

            if(location[0] != 0 && location[1] != 0){


                if(MainActivity.this.visibleItemCount == 6){

                    for(int i=0; i<MainActivity.this.visibleItemCount; i++){
                        View middleWantedView = listview.getChildAt(i);
                        if(MainActivity.flag){

                            MainActivity.height = middleWantedView.getHeight();
                            MainActivity.width = middleWantedView.getWidth();
                            MainActivity.flag = false;

                        }


                        middleWantedView.setScaleX(1);
                        middleWantedView.setScaleY(1);

                    }
                }




                if(MainActivity.this.visibleItemCount == 7){

                    View wantedView = listview.getChildAt(0);
                    wantedView.getLocationOnScreen(location);



                    float scaling = (float) (((float)location[1] - 150.0)/100.0);

                    Log.d("myLogs", "Scalling:" + scaling);



                    if(MainActivity.prevX == scaling)
                        scaling = (float) (scaling + 0.001);
                    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(MainActivity.prevX, scaling, MainActivity.prevX, scaling, 300, 100);

                    scaleAnimation.setDuration(1);

                    wantedView.setAnimation(scaleAnimation);
                    wantedView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);




                    View secondWantedView = listview.getChildAt(MainActivity.this.visibleItemCount-1);

                    float scaling2 = (float) (1.0 - scaling);


                    int padding = (-1) * (250 - location[1]);
                    padding = (int) (padding - (padding * 0.5));

                    Log.d("myLogs", "Padding:" + padding);
                    scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation((float) (1.0 - MainActivity.prevX), scaling2, (float) (1.0 -MainActivity.prevX), scaling2, 300, padding);


                    secondWantedView.setAnimation(scaleAnimation);
                    secondWantedView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);


                    MainActivity.prevX = scaling;

                    secondWantedView.setScaleX(scaling2);
                    secondWantedView.setScaleY(scaling2);



                }

            }


                  }});


        }});
      };






  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
  {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      outState.putStringArray(LABELSKEY, values);
      outState.putIntArray(COUNTERSKEY, counters);
  }

}`
```

Until the scrolling is going on, the animation is good. When scrolling stops, the first go to full size, instead of xx% from full size, and the last item also has problems.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
View row = findViewById(R.id.myrow);    
if(row.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    row.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
    row.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    row.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
    row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it's not exactly, what I need. I rewrite the question.